# Why do threads waiting on a ManualResetEvent continue waiting even when Close() is called?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, dispose

We were surprised to learn today that threads waiting on a `ManualResetEvent` continue waiting on the event even when it's closed.  We would have expected that calling `Close()` would implicitly signal the waiting threads.

We tracked this down as a reason some of our windows services were not shutting down as fast as we'd like.  We're changing all of our `Dispose` implementations that close `ManualResetEvent` references to call `Set` first.

Can anyone explain why `Close` doesn't implicitly call `Set`?  When would you want a waiting thread to continue waiting?

Here's our test code to demonstrate our findings:

```
    private static readonly Stopwatch _timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    public static void Test()
    {

        var sync = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state =>
                                         {
                                             Log("ThreadPool enter, waiting 250ms...");
                                             sync.WaitOne(250);
                                             Log("ThreadPool exit");
                                         });

        Log("Main sleeping 100");
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        Log("Main about to close");
        // sync.Set();      // Is Set called implicitly?  No...
        sync.Close();

        Log("Main waiting for exit 500ms");
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }

    private static void Log(string text)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0:0} {1}", _timer.ElapsedMilliseconds, text);  
    }
```

When we run this code with the `Set` call commented, we get this..

```
0 Main sleeping 100
0 ThreadPool enter, waiting 250ms...
103 Main about to close
103 Main waiting for exit 500ms
259 ThreadPool exit
```

When we explicitly call `Set` we get this..

```
0 Main sleeping 100
0 ThreadPool enter, waiting 250ms...
98 Main about to close
98 ThreadPool exit
98 Main waiting for exit 500ms
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Close` is a means of disposing of the object (`Close` and `Dispose` on this class yield identical behavior). It does not affect the state of the handle. To assume that, in all cases, the user would want a thread waiting on a handle that I closed to continue does not seem reasonable. In fact, the fact that the handle is *in use* should indicate that you shouldn't be calling `Close` in the first place.

It's not a matter of "why shouldn't `Set` be called implicitly?", it's a conceptual problem: If you're calling `Close`, *you should no longer care about the object*. Use `Set` and `Reset` to control the flow of execution among threads; don't call `Close` (or `Dispose`) on any object, `WaitHandle`s included, until they are no longer in use.

Comment: To add to that, it would cause hard to trace race conditions, even in the example of the OP, you'd get in trouble if the  sync.Close(); happened to be called before the thread pool got around to do sync.WaitOne();

Comment: The problem I have with this whole thing is that a WaitHandle is designed to support synchronization between threads, so I feel like Set on Close and event Wait after Close should be handled implicitly.  No worries though, we created a custom extended class that adds the functionality we want.

Comment: @Sam: I'm glad you found a solution, but, again, the problem is that your philosophy about the object's lifetime does not match that of the designers: the mere fact that you *care* about what state the handle is in means that you, by their design, are not yet ready to call `Close`.

Answer (score 1):

These synchronization events are based on Win32 wait handles, and `Close()` method only releases them (like `Dispose()`) without signaling, and waiting threads keep waiting.