# Disposing a manualResetevent on another thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586306/why-do-threads-waiting-on-a-manualresetevent-continue-waiting-even-when-close) I have a class with a private ManualReset event:

```
class A {
       private ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(true);
       private void Method(){
            //do something
            mre.Reset();
       }      
       public bool WaitForItem(int timeout){
           try{
               return mre.WaitOne(timeout)
           }catch(ObjectDisposedException){
               return false;
           }
      }
      public void Dispose(){
           mre.Dispose();
      }
}
```

How can I check that when `Dispose` is called `WaitForItem` method returns false, and doesn't block waiting.

The code is something similar to:

```
   A a = new A(1);
   a.Method();
   bool finished = true;
   Thread t1 = new Thread(() =>
   {
       finished = a.WaitForItem(Timeout.Infinite);
   });
   Thread t2 = new Thread(() =>
   {
       a.Dispose();
   });
   t1.Start();
   t2.Start();
   t1.Join();
   t2.Join();
```

The code blocks in waiting an item forever (at `t1.Join()`). I understood that calling `Close`, which is also a mean of disposing an object,  doesn't affect the state of the handle, but how can I exit the method with false (catching an `ObjectDisposedException`) ?

Even though instead of calling `a.Dispose()` on the second thread calling another method which Disposes the ManualResetEvent the call to WaitOne() it's blocked.

Comment: That you're running into this problem indicates that there's something fishy in the design of your application. But if you really need to do this, try a `ManualResetEventSlim` and use the [Wait(CancellationToken)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321783(v=vs.110).aspx) method. Just change your `Dispose` method to set the cancellation token before disposing the MRE. Honestly, though, you need to re-think your design. Something like this really shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ObjectDisposedException` is raised only when an object is already disposed before calling a member function. This is not happening in your case as function `mre.WaitOne(timeout)` is called before `mre.Dispose()`.

Once simple fix could be to call `mre.WaitOne(timeout)` function in a loop with a shorter timeout value. e.g. one want to have `10 seconds` timeout for `WaitForItem` function then `mre.WaitOne(timeout)` can be called with just 1 sec timeout and it will give up after 10 tries.

A typical implementation could for `WaitForItem` function is explained below. `WaitForItem` has got 3 possible return values.

1 = Set is triggered on `mre`
0 = Set is not triggered within specified timeout
-1 = Object is dispose before timeout.

```
public int WaitForItem(int timeout){
   try{
       int nReturnCode = 0;
       int nTimeElapsed = 0;
       while (true)
       {
           if (mre.WaitOne(1000))  //just wait for  1 second
           {
               nReturnCode = 1; //Set call on ManualResetEvent
               break;
           }
           else  //Timeout need to repeat
           {
               nTimeElapsed += 1000;
               if (nTimeElapsed > timeout)
               {
                   nReturnCode = 0; //timeout
                   break;
               }
           }
       }
       return nReturnCode;
   }catch(ObjectDisposedException){
       return -1; //Exception 
   }
```

}